# Customize the Default Web Page for a ClickOnce Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, deployment, clickonce

Sander, has wrote a related article for this...

http://todotnet.com/archive/2005/10/11/2595.aspx

unfortunately the code is in C#.

Which is the equivelant to the vb.net version?

Answer (score 2):

Converted with http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Xml.Xsl  
Imports System.Net

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("...url to the original publish.htm file..."), HttpWebRequest)
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

responseFromServer = responseFromServer.Replace(" ", " ")

Dim xml As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
xml.LoadXml(responseFromServer)

Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
Dim html As TextWriter = New StringWriter()
xslt.Load(Server.MapPath("CustomPublish.xsl"))
xslt.Transform(xml, Nothing, html)

Response.Write(html.ToString())
Response.[End]()
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write(html.ToString())
```

Capitalize.

Please comment [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487725/customize-the-default-web-page-for-a-clickonce-application/487767#487767) and check best answer, so we can keep in touch.